# Identify concrete type of object behind auto_ptr from core dump

Tags: c++, gdb, postmortem-debugging

I have an `auto_ptr<IFoo>`, where `IFoo` is an interface with just pure-virtual methods.

I now also have a core-file after a segmentation fault, where I'd really like to know what the concrete sub-class was behind this auto_ptr. As `dynamic_cast` works in the project, I think that RTTI must be available somehow, but I am unaware as how I would access this information via `gdb`?

The output I get is as follows:

```
(gdb) print this->obj._M_ptr
$22 = (class martin::IFoo *) 0x7418
```

What I'd really like to know, if the pointer belongs to an `IBar`or an `IBaz`.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Does `print typeid(*this->obj._M_ptr)` work?

Comment: try this Q/A: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9568201/gdb-show-typeinfo-of-some-data

Comment: typeid(...) just outputs 'No symbol "typeid" in current context.', which could mean that my cross-compiled GDB might be too old. In this case this would be bad luck. But thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What I'd really like to know, if the pointer belongs to an IBaror an IBaz

GDB should be able to tell you that. Use `(gdb) set print object on`. Documentation [here](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Print-Settings.html).

> When displaying a pointer to an object, identify the actual (derived)
>   type of the object rather than the declared type, using the virtual
>   function table. Note that the virtual function table is required—this
>   feature can only work for objects that have run-time type
>   identification; a single virtual method in the object's declared type
>   is sufficient.

Update:

> it only outputs the IFoo* interface

That likely means that the pointer really is pointing to `IFoo` (e.g. the object that was of type `IBar` or `IBaz` has already been destructed).

> Would working with dynamic_cast imply

Yes, `dynamic_cast` can't work without RTTI; if you are using `dynamic_cast`, `print object on` should just work.

Comment: Using `set print object on` was my first approach, but it only outputs the IFoo* interface. I begin to fear that there is no RTTI available. This is a core-dump from a stripped ARM binary, where I have the dbg files available as well. Would working with dynamic_cast imply that RTTI needs to be enabled or not?

Comment: @MartinC. Re: dynamic cast with no RTTI: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7687041/dynamic-cast-with-rtti-disabled

Comment: @shroudednight Thanks, good hint. I know for sure that there are no explicit disable flags in the compile process, but I will continue investigating in this direction.